# Correct way to outsource API calls in a MERN app (React client)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to outsource a few axios API calls within a React/MERN app. I need to do a GET request to the server when the client launches (in useEffect()). I've moved my axios function to an external file within the React client's folders and exported it. When testing with console.log, the function itself seems to work, as in it gets the correct data. However, when I use try to use that function's return value inside the client's useEffect() hook, I get undefined, or a Promise (that can't be a React child).

Here is my current code:

*App.js*

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState('Loading...');

useEffect(() => {
  setResponse(helloMessage());
}, [])
```

*CallAPI.js*

```
const helloMessage = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.message;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return 'Server not responding. Start the server and refresh this page.';
        })
    }
```

Exports and imports etc. are correctly in place. My only issue is probably the syntax, or whatever, of async/await in this case (I'm fairly sure that's the problem here). What is the correct way to make an API call using a function in an external file, to set the state on useEffect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the call, and in the callback change the state.

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState('Loading...');

useEffect(() => {
  helloMessage().then(res =>
   setResponse(res);
  )
}, [])
```

and need to return the promise from `helloMessage`

```
const helloMessage = () => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.message;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return 'Server not responding. Start the server and refresh this page.';
        })
    }
```